Ansible Not Running Custom Module
I have a module to parse data from a Cisco host but I am getting the following errors:

If I run the module with delegate_to: localhost, this is the error:
"Connection type local is not valid for this module"
If I run the module without delegating the task to localhost, this is
the error:    "Unexpected failure during module execution: No module
named    'my_custom_module'"

The main playbook calls the tasks as roles, like this:
---
- name: Create dynamic invegtory
  tags: check,apply
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  roles:
    - role: create_inventory

- name: get and compare data
  tags: check,apply
  hosts: run_group
  gather_facts: false
  roles:
    - get_data
    - compare_data

The task that runs my module is this:
- name: parse config lines
  config_parse:
    DEVICE_CONFIG: "{{ show_run['stdout'][0] }}"
  register: parsed_results

the create_inventory role uses the add_hosts module to build the inventory. Odd thing is, I've used this module before and didn't have this issue, not certain what is different about this playbook/environment.
Edit:
folder structure is:
main_playbook.yml
library/config_parse.py
roles/compare_data/tasks/main.yml
roles/create_inventory/tasks/main.yml
roles/get_data/tasks/main.yml

Ansible version 2.14.17
I don't think this is an issue with anything having changed on the Ansible server as all of my other playbooks with custom modules still work. My guess is this has something to do with the IOS hosts or how I am using roles....
Debug for the intrepid minds:::
TASK [compare_data : parse config lines] ***************************************
task path: /runner/project/roles/compare_data/tasks/ios_tasks.yaml:1
redirecting (type: connection) ansible.builtin.network_cli to ansible.netcommon.network_cli
[WARNING]: Collection ansible.netcommon does not support Ansible version
2.14.17
[WARNING]: Collection ansible.utils does not support Ansible version 2.14.17
redirecting (type: action) ansible.builtin.ios to cisco.ios.ios
redirecting (type: action) ansible.builtin.ios to cisco.ios.ios
The full traceback is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ansible/executor/task_executor.py", line 158, in run
    res = self._execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ansible/executor/task_executor.py", line 633, in _execute
    result = self._handler.run(task_vars=vars_copy)
  File "/usr/share/ansible/collections/ansible_collections/cisco/ios/plugins/action/ios.py", line 50, in run
    result = super(ActionModule, self).run(task_vars=task_vars)
  File "/usr/share/ansible/collections/ansible_collections/ansible/netcommon/plugins/action/network.py", line 44, in run
    filename, module = self._find_load_module()
  File "/usr/share/ansible/collections/ansible_collections/ansible/netcommon/plugins/action/network.py", line 260, in _find_load_module
    module = importlib.import_module(context.plugin_resolved_name)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'config_parse'
fatal: [10.1.1.1]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "Unexpected failure during module execution: No module named 'config_parse'",
    "stdout": ""
}


Where is you module located? What is your folder structure? How is your Ansible configured (ansible --version; ansible-config dump --only-changed)? Please [edit] those information in your question.

@β.εηοιτ.βε thanks for your question, added the requested details to the question.

I sort of found an answer.... this module works as expected so long as I remove underscores in the name. I tested another module in the same playbook and it works with and without underscores in the name. If I rename the module in question with underscores in the name, it fails every time. strange

"As long as I remove underscores in the name ... with underscores in the name, it fails every time" which is really strange as "Module name MUST use underscores instead of hyphens or spaces as a word separator". Furthermore I can't reproduce the issue. Maybe you can provide more debugging details.

@U880D I couldn't reproduce it with another module in the same project/library and playbook, only that one module exhibits the issue. Maybe file permission issues between Windows and WSL when I copied the file?  Here's more debug data added to the question:

"only that one module exhibits the issue. Maybe file permission issues between Windows and WSL when I copied the file?", maybe it is permission issue, see ls -alZ library and ls -alZ library/*. Or something with encoding.
